# Nested for loop error in shell script coding for Hive execution

Tags: shell, for-loop, hive

I am trying to print DDLs of all the tables present in a database of Hive.
I am using 2 nested 'for loops' in the shell script. As I am new to shell script, I don't know what mistake I am making.

the code is given below

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f DDL_table_names.txt

declare -a db_name=("dev_cmt" "dev_cmt_fleet")


for DB in "${db_name[@]}"
    do
    echo "$DB:">> DDL_table_names.txt
    for Tab in "$DB"
        do
          hive -e "use $DB;show create table $Tab;">>DDL_table_names.txt
          echo -e "\n" >> DDL_table_names.txt
      done 
    done

echo "Table file generated"
```

The error I am getting:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Table not found dev_cmt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `for Tab in "$DB"`
with `for Tab in $(hive -e "use $DB;show tables;")`

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for Tab in "$DB"
```

it is Tab is one of DB, the table does not exist in database.

Comment: Sorry, @007. I did not get it.  I have the same code that you suggested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).